# for loop wget directory array

Tags: command-line, bash, wget

i received this error when running the follow script

#### error

```
mus.sh: 8: mus.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")
```

#### script

```
#!/bin/bash

versions='57.0 58.0.1'
platforms='win64 win32'
locales='en-US es-ES'

for i in ${versions[@]}
do
for p in ${platforms[@]}
    do
        for l in ${locales[@]}
        do
            wget -c -A.mar "http://download.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/"$i"/update/"$p"/"$l"/"
        done
    done
done
```

Comment: What’s your question? Arrays in `bash` are built like that: `versions=(57.0 58.0.1)`

Comment: how make this loop work and mirror the necessaries folders

Comment: i tried to but the script don't work

Comment: this was a typo to copy the script on the forum

Comment: i need for a given arrays download recursively the target directories in the loop

Comment: The script works totally fine if I correct both the array syntax and the array names – what’s the problem?

Comment: Are those unix line-endings you have in this script? If not, `dos2unix` does the conversion.

Comment: i removed them and still have the same error output

Comment: @Alian Please [edit] your question to include the details you mentioned.

Comment: When you say "mirror the necessaries folders", do you mean you want the files to be downloaded and keep their remote directory structures? Like `57.0/update/win64/en-US/` and `57.0/update/win64/en-ES/` etc.

Comment: yes it's correct!

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't reproduce your error, but the script is incorrect at all. The incorrect part is the assignment of the values of `versions`, `platforms`, `locales` - currently these are variables, not arrays. Here is an illustration:

```
$ versions='57.0 58.0.1'
$ printf '%s\n' "${versions[@]}"
57.0 58.0.1
```

One of the ways to build [array in Bash](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-arrays), as [@dessert](https://askubuntu.com/users/507051/dessert) said, is by using  round brackets. Most commonly to:

- define an empty array: `array=()`,
- define an array and assign values: `array=('element 0' 'element 1')`,
- add elements to predefined array: `array+=('element 2' 'element 3')`,
- replace the value of a certain element (the first one in this case): `array[0]='new value'`,
- *in this case the [quote marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) are absolutely mandatory because of the white spaces in the values.*

Here is the result of the above illustration when an array is used:

```
$ unset versions 
$ versions=('57.0' '58.0.1')
$ printf '%s\n' "${versions[@]}"
57.0
58.0.1
```

According to that your script should look like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

versions=('57.0' '58.0.1')
platforms=('win64' 'win32')
locales=('en-US' 'es-ES')

for i in "${versions[@]}"
do
    for p in "${platforms[@]}"
    do
        for l in "${locales[@]}"
        do
             echo "$i : $p : $l"
        done
    done
done
```

Another minor mistake is your `wget` expression. It is better or simpler to quote the entire url. Use braces to separate the variables from the rest of the string:

```
wget -c -A.mar "http://.../releases/${i}/update/${p}/${l}/"
```

Comment: keep crash on error tests.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: @AlianDiazPerez, please `sudo apt install shellcheck` and do check of the script: `shellcheck test.sh`.

Comment: don't return any error

Comment: @AlianDiazPerez, I can't believe :-), please post the script in https://paste.ubuntu.com/ and provide the link.

Comment: i fill the same, its unbeliever, the link https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5ZDGGQjhqj/

Comment: @AlianDiazPerez, there is something wrong with your system environment, smell as your `/bin/bash` is linked to `sh`(`dash`) or something like this, because if I change the shebang from `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/bin/sh` I'm receiving [the same error message](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Q7Gc2bTNTZ/). Try with [`readlink -f $(command -v bash)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37423392/6543935) and `bash --version` to investigate.

Comment: alian@archive:/var/www/mozilla$ sudo bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)